# capturing only certain characters in regular expression by python

Tags: python

I'm trying to create pattern that detects certain strings. Basically, the purpose is if detect 'ABCDEF' in a string then return "true". but between 'ABC' and 'DEF', there would be (L+count) or (number) or not like examples below. BTW all examples below return "true".
It would be really appreciate if some one can advise how to ignore those combo of number and characters between "ABC" and "DEF"?

```
 ABC(L30)(345)DEF, ABC(L2)(45)DEF, ABCDEF, ABC(L10)DEF, ABC(2)DEF
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex compose thinking path:

- Start with ABC
- Ends with DEF
- Either (L[0-9]+) or ([0-9]+) or empty

> ```
> #!/usr/bin/python
> import re
> r=re.compile("ABC(\(L[0-9]+\)|\([0-9]+\)|)*DEF");
> lines = [
>         "ABC(L30)(345)DEF",
>         "ABC(L2)(45)DEF",
>         "ABC(L30)DEF",
>         "ABC(345)DEF",
>         "ABCDEF",
>         "ABCxyzDEF",
>         "ABC(L)DEF",
>         "ABC(A)DEF",
>         "ABC()DEF",
> ]
> for str in lines:
>         if r.match(str):
>                 print "    match : %s" % str
>         else:
>                 print "not match : %s" % str
> ```

Output:

> ```
>     match : ABC(L30)(345)DEF
>     match : ABC(L2)(45)DEF
>     match : ABC(L30)DEF
>     match : ABC(345)DEF
>     match : ABCDEF
> not match : ABCxyzDEF
> not match : ABC(L)DEF
> not match : ABC(A)DEF
> not match : ABC()DEF
> ```

Comment: thank you Ken, this is the solution what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

```
def is_in(string_,word_):

    import re

    return word_ in [''.join(re.split('\(.+?\)\(.+?\)|\(.+?\)',string_))][0]


s = "ABC(L30)(345)DEF, ABC(L2)(45)DEF, ABCDEF, ABC(L10)DEF, ABC(2)DEF"

print(is_in(s,'ABCDEF'))

True
```

Comment: I revised the question. the purpose is to return "true" if it detects "ABCDEF" in a string. and all above 5 cases shows different cases that returns "True".